# Accessing Hyperlink file explorer using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, userform

I am creating a spreadsheet to act as a central point of all the documentation relevant to a project, so that all the quotes, drawings etc will all be in a single excel document with hyperlinks to the files along with information about them. (e.g. for a drawing, the drawing name and number will be requested)

I want to do this through a userform in order to ensure sufficient information is supplied as this will be referenced during audits.

But I am having difficulty with the hyperlink part as there may not be a known address/name that allows me to use the hyperlinks.add method.

What would be optimal is the ability to click the Hyperlink button on the ribbon from inside the userform.

This is my first time asking a question, been trawling through stack overflow for a while now though. But I am open to suggestions about asking better questions etc.

Cheers.

Comment: What type of links are you trying to create?  To files, or to URL's (or both) ?

Comment: Only to files, the answer below is perfect, I did not know about that application.dialogs property until just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Append Hyperlink to list using the Insert Hyperlink Dialog

[image]

```
Private Sub btnInsertHyperlink_Click()
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Did not know about the application dialogs property before and didn't find it in my searches. Still a bit of a rookie. Thanks for your help.